# spacemacs combine yas-snippet + autocomplete

Tags: spacemacs, company-mode

I am pretty new to spacemacs and I am still trying to configure it to my needs.
In emacs I use yas-snippet a lot and I am fond of the autocomplete feature in spacemacs.

Apparently there is a way to combine the two via company-mode that I found [on github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/385), but I have no idea where I have to place the configurations.

I hope someone can help me. I would like to avoid setting a new key for company-yasnippet because the integration with the autocomplete drop menu would greatly speed up the working process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find what you need somewhere in the autocompletion layer documentation.  Have a look at this documentation by pressing "spacebar h spacebar" and then typing "auto-completion". or look at this link
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bcompletion/auto-completion

I don't use company-mode, but currently I'm happy typing "spacebar i s" whenever I want to add a yasnippet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have implemented to code recommended in the auto-complete documentation. Does not react at the moment, but for now spacebar i s will do.